# Prepend element and add function to it

Tags: jquery

How to make working the function to a prepended element? Sorry if the question sounds wrong. Now Im using this code:

```
function listOfProduct() {
    $('.list-of-product li').prepend('<input type="checkbox" name="list-of-product"><label class="list-of-product-element"></label>');
    $('.list-of-product li').each(function (i) {
        i++ ;
        $(this).prev('input').attr('id', 'list-of-product-' + i);
        $(this).prop('for', 'list-of-product-' + i);
    });
}
```

I add to `<li>` these elements which are inside the `prepend()`and after that I want dynamicaly add specific attributes. Now its not working. Can anyone explain me why?

Comment: Are there multple li?  Your prepending to lis.  Making sure your not thinking your creating new lis.

Comment: I am prepending to multiple lis, NOT new one.

Comment: So your adding new fields to every existing li and this is intended

Comment: @NeedHate I believe, in the second one, you need to use `$('.list-of-product li label')` because, `for` is for `<label>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, in the second one, you need to use `$('.list-of-product li label')` because, `for` is for `<label>`. And also, the label's previous is the `<input />`.

Try this:

```
function listOfProduct() {
    $('.list-of-product li').prepend('<input type="checkbox" name="list-of-product"><label class="list-of-product-element"></label>');
    $('.list-of-product li label').each(function (i) {
        i++ ;
        $(this).prev('input').attr('id', 'list-of-product-' + i);
        $(this).attr('for', 'list-of-product-' + i);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't have an `<input>` as previous element to an `<li>`...they are children of the `<li>`

try:

```
$('.list-of-product li').each(function (i) {
        i++ ;
        $(this).find('input').attr('id', 'list-of-product-' + i);
        $(this).find('label').prop('for', 'list-of-product-' + i);
});
```

Comment: Guess our answers technically do the same. `:)`

Comment: Sweet, i was concerned for a moment.

Comment: anyway, Shao Kahn wins... Thanks guys, you helped me!